# Fragment extends ListFragment cant open in MainActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

Kindly tell me how to open A Fragment extends ListFragment from MainActivity.java?

Here is My code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

   ImageView imageView1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    //String currentUserId = currentUser.getObjectId().toString().trim();

    if (currentUser != null) {
        // do stuff with the user


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

       // final View headerLayout = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);
        final View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView text = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.TxtUsernametitle);
        TextView Tmail = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textmail);
        imageView1 = (ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.profile_image2);


        String Tusern = currentUser.getUsername();
        String Tmails = currentUser.getEmail();
        text.setText(Tusern);
        Tmail.setText(Tmails);
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Profile");
        String UsiD = currentUser.getObjectId();
        query.whereEqualTo("userID",UsiD);
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object.get("picture");
                    if (object.get("picture") != null) {
                        String imgpath = fileObject.getUrl();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imgpath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(imgpath).into(imageView1);
                    } else {
                        imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });



   FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
   fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new MainFragments()).commit();



    } else {
        // show the signup or login screen
        Intent takeUsertoLogin = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
       startActivity(takeUsertoLogin);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    FragmentManager fm2 =getFragmentManager();

    int id = item.getItemId();
switch (id){
    case R.id.Ads_page:
        fm2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new UpdateFragment()).commit();
        break;

}
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new ImportFragments()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new MainFragments()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ParseUser.logOut();
}
}
```

MainFragments:

```
    public class MainFragments extends ListFragment {
    protected List<ParseObject> Ads;
Button btn_LogOut;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,container, false);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Ads");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {


        @Override
public void done(List<ParseObject> Adsobjects, ParseException e) {
    if(e==null){
        Ads=Adsobjects;
        AdsAdapter adapter =new AdsAdapter(getListView().getContext(),Ads);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }else{

    }

}
});



    btn_LogOut=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonlogout);

    btn_LogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseUser.logOut();
            updateDetail();

        }
    });
    return rootView;


  }

public void updateDetail() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

I would like to open this MainFragment to MainActivity.

I tried with this :

FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new MainFragments()).commit();

It works if MainFragment extends Fragment but My ListView doesn't work...

Your Help will be appreciated!
Regards,
Marwan

Comment: In your MainFragments class are you importing android.app.ListFragment or android.support.v4.app.ListFragment?

Comment: it is import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of the ListFragment.  One built into the framework (android.app.ListFragment) and one which is part of the support library (android.support.v4.app.ListFragment).

Using the support library version lets you target versions of Android which were around before Fragments were introduced.  You've got two options:

If you want to continue to use the support library version for maximum compatibility you need to change which FragmentManager you use in your Activity by doing:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Alternatively if you want to use the framework version you just need to change the import statement in your Fragment to:

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you saved my time ;)